# configure pi as a usb gadget, add vivid driver to the image, build and run code

Tags: usb, video, gadget

Need to configure RPi as a USB UVC (video camera gadget). As far as I understand [here is how it can be done](http://isticktoit.net/?p=1383). Then I need to test [this application](https://github.com/cyboflash/uvc-gadget). Instructions on how to do it located [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/90a6cd503982bfd33ce8c70eb49bd2dd33bc6325/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L695-L731).

Questions

1. How can I add [Virtual Video Driver](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/media/v4l-drivers/vivid.html) to the Raspberry PI image?
2. How can I cross compile [this code](https://github.com/cyboflash/uvc-gadget) on my host, for it later to be copied to the RPi. I need this option just in case I would not be able to compile it directly on RPi. Just a precaution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is with a Pi Zero (or old Pi model A/A+). OTG won't work on a Pi 3 or most other models.

I'll answer your second question first because it'll come in handy for question 1).

For 2), once you are set up to [cross-compile the kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md)--having retrieved the tools and set up your `PATH`--you'll be ready to compile uvc-gadget similarly:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

uvc-gadget is a small application so I actually find it more convenient to to make changes and build on the Pi Zero. Unfortunately, the same is not true for the kernel.

The latest Raspbian 9 Stretch defaults to a gcc 6 toolchain/libc while the tools repo is apparently still gcc 4.9. You may have to revert to Raspbian 8 Jessie to avoid getting a segfault even on a hello world application, or find an updated toolchain.

For 1), you'll need to configure the kernel for `CONFIG_VIDEO_VIVID` and recompile. After you have gotten the hang of building the kernel + modules and uploading it to your Pi,

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- menuconfig
```

Device Drivers -> Multimedia Support -> Media test drivers -> Virtual Video Test Driver (set to M)

then recompile the kernel + modules and it should generate a `vivid.ko` file. I have only confirmed that it compiles, not necessarily loads or runs properly. To date my testing with `uvc-gadget` on a Pi zero has relied on synthetic image data (`-d`).